# Vue js - Vue router - Login and refresh data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to make an Vue js application. Have succeded in making an auth request, check if the user is logged in etc.

Upon login i want to fetch some data and store it in localStorage. The problem is that the localStorage is not reactive and there fore when i land on the dashboard on a successful login the data (E.g userdata) is not accessable if i don't press a route link. Then in can access the data.

So how do i "emualte" or make an soft refresh like i press a link and change route upon login.

This is my login component, the localStorage data is set in the auth script.

```
<template>
  <div id="loginInput">

      <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-header">
            <img src="../assets/images/Logotype.png">
        </div>
        <div class="login-body">
            <div v-show="!forgot">
                <h1>Log in</h1>
                <form @submit.prevent="login" autocomplete="off"> 
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" v-model="email" />
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" v-model="pass" />
                    <button class="btn btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                    <p v-if="error" class="error">Bad login information</p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div v-show="forgot">
                <h1>Forgott password</h1>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" v-model="emailForgot" />
                <button class="btn btn-block" type="button">Reset password</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-footer">
            <a href="#" v-show="!forgot" v-on:click.prevent="forgot = true">Forgot password?</a>
            <a href="#" v-show="forgot" v-on:click.prevent="forgot = false">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import auth from '@/assets/js/auth'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                email: '',
                pass: '',
                emailForgot: '',
                forgot: false,
                error: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login () {

                auth.login(this.email, this.pass, loggedIn => {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    this.error = true
                } else {
                    this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
                }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
  .error {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I think that localstorage is not good place to keep data. Propably the best solution is to use vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html
If you still want to use localstorage, then you should watch $route in dashboard and get data from localstorage if you came to dashboard from login page

Comment: @TomaszKostuch It seems like super overkill to bring in `vuex` just for the sake of storing a simple piece of data. `vuex` just sits on top of `localStorage` (unless you define a different storage type) anyway.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but it seems like you could use the router.beforeEach to load the data from localStorage https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html. Or yea I would probably go with adding vuex since it seems your application isn't limited to this scope.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Why not use tool that is designed to management state and data flow? It's not big library and for sure it will not overload app (10kb min)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments, implemented Vuex and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by added Vuex to the application. It helped me to both to store data to be accessed to all the components.

With Vuex i could also make the localStorage reactive and can now update localStorage and in will change all thru the components.

https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/vue-js-using-localstorage-with-the-vuex-store